# How to make a control array of buttons or togglers?

Tags: gui-construction, button, list-manipulation

## An array of buttons

From time to time I wish I had a [*control array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the sort native to Visual Basic.

A control array of buttons would be a table of buttons in which each button "knows" its location in the table.  For example If I click on the button in the second row and third column, it would do something with the respective row and column of some array that holds data.

Ideally *Mathematica* would have something like a `ButtonTable`, a 2D version of `ButtonBar`.

---

As a work around, I've come up with this:

```
a = Array[0 &, {8, 4}]
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
ClickPane[Dynamic[Graphics[{Black, Point[pt]},
GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
GridLines -> {Range[1, 5], Range[-8, 0]},
PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, -8}},
ImageSize -> 130]], (pt = #; 
a[[Sequence @@ Reverse@Abs[Floor@ pt]]] = Reverse@Abs[Floor@ pt]; 
Print[a]) &]]
```

It (clumsily) draws a table of 8 rows and 4 columns. This corresponds to an 8 by 4 matrix, `a`, which initially holds only zeros. When I click on a "cell" it, the `ClickPane` returns its integer coordinates and also updates the respective element in `a` with it's value. (Don't worry about the `Point`. I used it to check positions.  Now that I think of it, `MousePosition` may be useful to capture the coordinates.)

In a real life application, it would do something useful with the value of the respective array element. Also, I would want there to be labels in each cell of the graphical representation. Unfortunately, with the above code I'd have to enter this labels manually. If the control array were a true control array, each button (or toggler) would have its own label. And there would be no need to manually lay out the buttons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For a clickable, interactive `ArrayPlot`, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116452/89).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simplicity, I'm using function downvalues as a backend (and not an array)

```
(* Define functions *)
bTable[action_, fArray_, dims_]:= Grid@Array[Button[{#1, #2}, action[fArray, #1, #2]]&, dims]
action[fArray_, x_, y_] := (fArray[x, y] = fArray[x, y] + 1) (* or whatever *)

(* Initialize *)
dims = {3, 3};
Array[(f[#1, #2] = 0) &, dims];

(* Run *)
Row[{bTable[action, f, dims], Dynamic@ArrayPlot@Array[f@## &, dims]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could add another array containing the labels as a parameter for `bTable[ ]`

Comment: Very elegant!  I can see how this could be useful in all kinds of circumstances, with other controls.

Answer (score 5):

`SparseArray` is another tool for constructing arrays with regular patterns,

```
SparseArray[{
   {i_, j_} :> Button[
     Row[{"(", i, ",", j, ")"}],
     actfunc[i, j]]
   }, {3, 4}] // Grid
```

You can define/redefine your button function later,

```
Clear[actfunc]
actfunc[i_, j_] := arry[[i, j]] = RandomReal[]
```

Then your data,

```
arry = ConstantArray[0, {3, 4}];
Dynamic[arry // ArrayPlot]
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach where I simulated a grid of togglers: whichever button is pushed, its position is added to/removed from `list`. It is general enough to lay out ragged tables.

```
num = 27; (* number of buttons *)
edge = 6;    (* edge size of grid *)

list = {};
Dynamic@list
Grid[MapIndexed[
  Button[#2, list = If[MemberQ[list, #2], DeleteCases[list, #2], Append[list, #2]], 
    Appearance -> Dynamic@{"Palette", If[MemberQ[list, #2], "Pressed", "Normal"]}] &, 
  Partition[Range@num, edge, edge, {1, 1}, {}], {2}],
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Works nicely with one dimensional arrays.