# How can I make a clickable ArrayPlot that returns input?

Tags: dynamic, visualization, list-manipulation

I would like to create a dynamic `ArrayPlot` so that the rectangles, when clicked, provide the input. Can I use `ArrayPlot` for this? Or is there something else I should have to use?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "provide input"?

Comment: See also: http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/05/09/2048/ It is not possible to use `ArrayPlot` directly because `ArrayPlot` produces a `Raster` object.  This is a single graphics element.  You'd ideally need separate graphics elements for each clickable square.

Comment: I wanted to be able to add squares to an array, and then generate the rest of the array based off of those squares selected.

Comment: Imagine that you don't actually know what you are asking and you only read the question ("I want a dynamic ArrayPlot so that the squares, when clicked, provide input") and then "I wanted to be able to add squares to an array, and then generate the rest of the array based off of those squares selected". Do you think you could have worked out what's being asked?

Comment: Possibly the confusion comes from many new users being used to discussion forums.  So they post a discussion starter, and see where it goes.  StackExchange is a Q/A platoform, and it's not desgined for discussion.  While it is possible to clarify questions (and it regularly happens), it is preferable that the original question be clear, and contain all information that's necessary to answer it.

Comment: @Szabolcs and Closers: I suggest reopening as it is highly nontrivial how to do it robustly for an `ArrayPlot`, as the `ArrayPlot` construct is not as simple as a grid of rectangles arranged in a similar way as `Grid` does: for example, it respects data ranges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ArrayPlot` is much more than just a simple array like `Grid`: it represents a ranged 2D dataset, and its visualization can be finetuned by options like `DataReversed` and `DataRange`. These features make it quite complicated to reproduce the same layout and order with `Grid`.

Here I offer `AnnotatedArrayPlot` which comes in handy when your dataset is more than just a flat 2D array. The dynamic interface allows highlighting individual cells and possibly interacting with them. `AnnotatedArrayPlot` works the same way as `ArrayPlot` and accepts the same options plus `Enabled`, `HighlightCoordinates`, `HighlightStyle` and `HighlightElementFunction`.

```
data = {{Missing["HasSomeMoreData"], GrayLevel[
    1], {RGBColor[0, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], GrayLevel[1]}, 
    RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}, {GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[0.5], RGBColor[
    1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]}, {GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[1], 
    GrayLevel[0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}};

{ArrayPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-4, 0}, {-2, 0}}, FrameTicks -> All],
 AnnotatedArrayPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-4, 0}, {-2, 0}}, 
  FrameTicks -> All,
  HighlightElementFunction -> (Tooltip[
      Button[{Rectangle @@ #2}, Print@{#3, #4}], #4] &)]}
```

[image]

The option `HighlightElementFunction` recieves the following values:

- `#1` = the actual {$x$, $y$} center coordinates of the selected cell within the graphics;
- `#2` = the lower left and upper right corner coordinates of the selected cell;
- `#3` = the {$i$, $j$} indices of the selected cell within the data array;
- `#4` = the selected element from the input data array.

### Examples

```
{{
   ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}, 
    ColorRules -> {1 -> Pink, 0 -> Yellow}, ImageSize -> 100],
   ArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
    {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 100],
   ArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}},
     DataRange -> {{1, 3}, {0, 1}}, FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> 100],
   ArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
    ImageSize -> 100, DataRange -> {{1, 2}, {0, 1}}],
   ArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}}\[Transpose], 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> 70],
   ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 20}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    ImageSize -> 100]
  },{
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}},
    ColorRules -> {1 -> Pink, 0 -> Yellow}, ImageSize -> 100],
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]},
    {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 100],
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
      RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}}, DataRange -> {{1, 3}, {0, 1}}, FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> 100],
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
    ImageSize -> 100, DataRange -> {{1, 2}, {0, 1}}],
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}}\[Transpose],
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> 70],
   AnnotatedArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 20}], 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 100]
   }} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
resolveSymbolicPosition[pos_, def_List] := Switch[pos,
   Center | Left | Right | {Center} | {Left} | {Right}, {pos, 
    Last@def},
   Top | Bottom | {Top} | {Bottom}, {First@def, pos},
   {Center | Left | Right, Center | Top | Bottom, ___}, Take[pos, 2],
   None | {None} | {None, None}, {None, None},
   _Symbol, def,
   _?NumericQ, {pos, Last@def},
   {__?NumericQ}, PadRight[pos, 2, def],
   _, def];

Options[AnnotatedArrayPlot] = Join[Options@ArrayPlot, {
    Method -> "Queued",(* NOTE: 
    By default "Queued" is used so that long calculations are \
finished before preemption. *)
    Enabled -> True,(*PlotRangeClipping\[Rule]True,*)
    HighlightCoordinates -> None,
    HighlightStyle -> 
     Directive[EdgeForm@{GrayLevel[0, .5], AbsoluteThickness@1}, 
      FaceForm@GrayLevel[1, .3]],
    HighlightElementFunction -> (Tooltip[Rectangle @@ #2, #4] &)}];
AnnotatedArrayPlot[data : {__List}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{dd, emptyQ = data === {{}}, xr, yr, init, fun, dr, rev, ar, 
    ops, m, n},
   {init, fun, dr, rev, ar} = 
    OptionValue@{HighlightCoordinates, HighlightElementFunction, 
      DataRange, DataReversed, AspectRatio};
   ops = DeleteCases[
     FilterRules[Flatten@{opts}, Options@ArrayPlot], _[
      Epilog | DataRange | DataReversed, _]];
   {m, n} = {Max[Length /@ data], Length@data};
   dd = If[ArrayQ@data, data, PadRight[data, {n, m}, None]];
   {xr, yr} = 
    Switch[rev, Automatic, {False, False}, _List, 
     PadRight[rev, 2, False], _, PadRight[{rev}, 2, False]];
   (*Print@{emptyQ,{m,n},{xr,yr},dd};*)

   DynamicModule[{rx, ry, px, py, dx, dy, d, x, y, bx, by, i, j, elem,
      update, f = fun, rect},
    {rx, ry} = Switch[dr, All | Automatic, {{1, m}, {1, n}}, _, dr];
    {dx, dy} = 
     MapThread[
      If[#2 == 1, 1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/(#2 - 1)] &, {{rx, ry}, {m, 
        n}}];
    {px, py} = {rx + {-dx, dx}/2, ry + {-dy, dy}/2} + 
      If[dr === All, 0, Switch[{m, n},
        {1, 1}, {{dx, 0}, {dy, 0}},
        {1, _}, {{dx, 0}, {dy, dy}/2},
        {_, 1}, {{dx, dx}/2, {dy, 0}},
        _, {{dx, dx}, {dy, dy}}/2]];
    rect = Reverse@{py, px}\[Transpose] - {{0, 0}, {dx, dy}};
    d = Switch[{xr, yr}, {True, True}, Reverse, {False, False}, 
       Map@Reverse, {False, True}, 
       Reverse /@ Reverse@# &, {True, False}, Identity]@Transpose@dd;
    init = 
     resolveSymbolicPosition[
       init, {Left, Bottom}] /. {Left -> First@ry, Right -> Last@ry, 
       Bottom -> First@rx, Top -> Last@rx};
    update[{None, None}] := ({x, y} = {i, j} = {None, None}; 
      elem = None; {bx, by} = {{}, {}});
    update[pos_] := (
      {x, y} = pos;
      {bx, by} = {{x, y} - {dx, dy}/2, {x, y} + {dx, dy}/2};
      {i, j} = 
       Ceiling@MapThread[
         Rescale, {{x, y}, {px, py}, {{1, m}, {1, n}}}, 1];
      elem = If[emptyQ, Null, d[[i, j]]];);
    update@If[emptyQ, {None, None}, init];
    LocatorPane[
     Dynamic[{x, y}, update@# &],
     EventHandler[
      ArrayPlot[dd,
       DataRange -> dr, DataReversed -> {xr, yr}, ops,
       Epilog -> {
         OptionValue@Epilog,
         If[emptyQ, {}, 
          Flatten@{OptionValue@HighlightStyle, 
            Dynamic[
             If[x === None, {}, f[{x, y}, {bx, by}, {i, j}, elem]], 
             TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]}]
         }],
      "MouseExited" :> ({x, y} = {None, None}; update@{x, y}), 
      Method -> OptionValue@Method],
     Append[rect, {dx, dy}],
     AutoAction -> True, Appearance -> None, 
     LocatorAutoCreate -> False, Enabled -> OptionValue@Enabled]
    ]];
```